# How to serialize a linked list implemented in java?

Tags: java, serialization

I read online that serialization can be omitted for derived objects by declaring them as transient. But, in case of linked list the links are memory references between objects. So, should I convert it to array and store the array representation?

Comment: Either way its a List, its representation when serialized does not have to be exactly the same as its representation in memory. Thus storing it as an array sounds fine to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how Java serializes `LinkedList`: it fetches all elements and writes them to the `ObjectOutputStream`, together with the size. And of course declares the `header` entry `transient`

See the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods of `LinkedList`:

```
// Write out any hidden serialization magic
s.defaultWriteObject();

// Write out size
s.writeInt(size);

// Write out all elements in the proper order.
for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next)
    s.writeObject(e.element);
```

Comment: The reason for this is that the "normal" serialization would for each entry recursively invoke another `writeObject(e)`, and for long lists this would give a `StackOverflowError`. The iterative serialization avoids this.