# Serialization of object causes RuntimeException on Android

Tags: java, android, ioexception, serializable

I'm having problems getting my app to retain its state when it becomes paused due to switching away from it. I've overloaded the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods to save and restore the only object which contains the variables important to my application's state (consisting of a bunch of arrays, arraylists, hashsets, enumerations, and primitives). Unfortunately, switching away from my app causes it to crash with a serialization error. Here is the code I have for saving and restoring the state:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Next line causes error when switching apps, but not when rotating screen
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("board", board);
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    board = (Board)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("board");
}
```

As far as I can tell, my only problem is that the Board object I've created is not serializable. However, it implements Serializable and defines its serialVersionUID, so I don't know what more I need to do to make it serializable. Normally that is all that's necessary.
I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to save and retrieve instances of objects than the getSerializable method?
2. What can I do to make my object serialize without throwing a runtime exception?

I find this exception particularly odd because my object seems to serialize without problems when the screen is rotated, but causes an error when the app is switched out. I've included the stack trace below, in case it's relevant. I can also post code from the object in question (Board) if requested. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
08-05 18:10:32.322  32059-32059/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.android.Board)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1279)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1233)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1627)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2252)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3179)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.android.Square
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1205)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1662)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1205)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1662)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1274)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: stupid question, have you serialized your class ***com.example.android.Square***?

Comment: Good question; I didn't realize that it was necessary. I didn't notice that line in the massive stack trace. That changed my error; now it looks like a HashSet is causing a StackOverflowError. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

As drurenia pointed out in his comment, I needed to add `implements Serializable` to my Square class, which was one of the members contained in my Board class.
My second problem was caused by circular references in the Square class, since each Square contains a reference to each of its neighbors. It should be solvable by implementing `readObject` and `writeObject` inside the Board class. More information on dealing with circular references during serialization can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317876/how-to-serialize-a-linked-list-implemented-in-java/5317905#5317905).

Comment: Your second problem was not caused by circular references. Serialization already handles circular references correctly, and there is nothing in the answer you cited about circular references at all. What you did, and what the answer you cited does, is solve a *stack overflow* problem.

Comment: Perhaps 'circular reference' is the wrong term. What I meant was that it was caused by the fact that my Square class contained references to other Square objects. This was causing a stack overflow during serialization, so I had to add implement writeObject manually to avoid the infinite recursion in the default implementation.

Paŭlo Ebermann's comment in the link I provided explains how recursion in the default implementation causes a stack overflow due to the fact that the object references its own type.