# How serialization work in LinkedList?

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list, transient

I don't understand how LinkedList understand's where the first and last element is after deserialization.
Because fields have the following structure

```
/**
 * Pointer to first node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> first;

/**
 * Pointer to last node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> last;
```

Can anyone help understand it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize a linked list implemented in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317876/how-to-serialize-a-linked-list-implemented-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`LinkedList` method `readObject`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.readObject%28java.io.ObjectInputStream%29) determines what `first` and `last` refer to during the reconstruction of the list.  Here's the code from the link:

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read in any hidden serialization magic
    s.defaultReadObject();

    // Read in size
    int size = s.readInt();

    // Read in all elements in the proper order.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        linkLast((E)s.readObject());
}
```

The `linkLast` method keeps track of `first` and `last`.  It initializes `first` and `last` on the first node to be reconstructed and it updates `last` with each newly reconstructed node.

```
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```